# appcelerator titanium studio not starting

Tags: javascript, installation, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have just tried to install fresh appcelerator titanium studio, I am able to install it properly but when I am trying to start it then it shows the following error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Following is my

> appc info

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 9.5.0
  npm Version                 = 5.6.0

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.13
  Core Package                = 7.0.3

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.1.0
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.44

Titanium SDKs
  7.1.1.GA
    Version                   = 7.1.1
    Install Location          = /Users/webwerks/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.1.1.GA
    Platforms                 = iphone, android
    git Hash                  = 1708b2d
    git Timestamp             = 4/19/2018 18:20
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.45

Mac OS X
  Command Line Tools          = installed

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Java Development Kit
  Version                     = 9_181
  Java Home                   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home

Genymotion
  Path                        = /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS
  Genymotion Executable       = /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/genymotion
  Genymotion Player           = /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS/player
  Home                        = /Users/webwerks/.Genymobile/Genymotion

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage
  Version                     = 5.2.8r121009

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = /Users/webwerks/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
  SDK Path                    = /Users/webwerks/Library/Android/sdk
```

And Log File is as follows:

```
!SESSION 2018-05-16 17:55:58.244 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/webwerks/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/webwerks/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY VisualUI 4 0 2018-05-16 17:56:04.566
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: VisualUI [3]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.core; bundle-version="3.1.2.1512467051"; singleton:="true"
       com.appcelerator.titanium.core [30]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core; bundle-version="1.0.0.1512401448"; singleton:="true"
              com.appcelerator.titanium.daemon.core [31]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.msgpack-core
```

I have tried to run appc setup on terminal as well but it still not worked.

Please let me to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your jdk version. Remove(delete created folder) installed java from path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ and then try to install appcelerator.dmg, it will automatically ask for download jdk and it will download required version of jdk.

Or Else, download this jdk version(1.8.0_131) and replace that jdk with this version. I hope it will help you.